# Objective C notify application when call is ended

Tags: objective-c, xcode, listener

In my application when i click on a button a call is launched like this :

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I want to be notified when user ended his call not simply come back to the application when call ended, how can i add a listener ?

any help is welcome

Comment: @Abizern it s not the same, i want to know when come back to application and call a function

Comment: Thats not possible. But, does it work for you to add the following observer? UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. this notifies the view controller you are in that you are back.

Comment: it's not exactly what i want, i want to be notified when user start call and end the call, because user can back to the application and the call it s not ended. i do a listener easaly on android, but it seems like you say not possble on ios, i will use just UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification

Comment: Thats not possible. Its apple privacy policy. I guess you are forced to ask the user if he finished when he come back.

Comment: That call is on your website or any other website?If it is on your website then it is somehow or partially possible to do this.